# Reading Serial Data in Matlab and Display it continuously on Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, serial-port, matlab-guide

I am receiving some data on serial port. I have seen it using Hyper terminal or Real Term. Now I want that data to be read in Matlab function and to be displayed on Matlab GUI.

I need data to be displayed in real time as long as Data is available at Serial port.

As I am totally new to the Matlab environment, Could anybody please suggest data or code related to the same.

Please help.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for fopen(serial) has a good example on how to read/write data on a serial port. [fopen(serial) Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.fopen.html).

Once you have your data, you have a variety of options to animate the data. [Line Animations Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/line-animation-of-streaming-data.html) has some code examples to accomplish this.